# Decision Tree Keeps Using Y-variable in Tree Decision Making

Tags: r, tree, classification, decision-tree

I'm using C5.0 to make a decision tree, and it's using my class label in the tree. A snippet of my data is below.

trainX

```
V1                V2     V3         V4 V5                  V6
1 39         State-gov  77516  Bachelors 13       Never-married
2 50  Self-emp-not-inc  83311  Bachelors 13  Married-civ-spouse
3 38           Private 215646    HS-grad  9            Divorced
4 53           Private 234721       11th  7  Married-civ-spouse
5 28           Private 338409  Bachelors 13  Married-civ-spouse
          V7             V8     V9     V10  V11 V12 V13            V14
1       Adm-clerical  Not-in-family  White    Male 2174   0  40  United-States
2    Exec-managerial        Husband  White    Male    0   0  13  United-States
3  Handlers-cleaners  Not-in-family  White    Male    0   0  40  United-States
4  Handlers-cleaners        Husband  Black    Male    0   0  40  United-States
5     Prof-specialty           Wife  Black  Female    0   0  40           Cuba
```

trainY

```
[1]  <=50K  <=50K  <=50K  <=50K  <=50K
```

There are cases in my data of >50K as well, this snippet of 5 just did not contain any.

When I make my tree, this is the code I use

```
library(C50)

trainX = X[1:100,]
trainY = Y[1:100]
testX = X[101:150,]
testY = Y[101:150]

model = C5.0(trainX, trainY)
summary(model)
```

And the output I get is...

```
Decision tree:
 <=50K (100/25)
```

Evaluation on training data (100 cases):

```
    Decision Tree   
  ----------------  
  Size      Errors  

     1   25(25.0%)   <<


   (a)   (b)    <-classified as
  ----  ----
    75          (a): class <=50K
    25          (b): class >50K
```

What am I doing wrong that it's using the classification as part of the tree?

EDIT - DPUTS below of Head. Still gives me the same issue, where its making a Decision Tree using the split as <=50K or >50K, which is my "Y" output and thus shouldn't be part of the decision making process.

trainX

```
structure(list(V1 = c(39L, 50L, 38L, 53L, 28L, 37L), V2 = structure(c(8L, 
7L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c(" ?", " Federal-gov", " Local-gov", 
" Never-worked", " Private", " Self-emp-inc", " Self-emp-not-inc", 
" State-gov", " Without-pay"), class = "factor"), V3 = c(77516L, 
83311L, 215646L, 234721L, 338409L, 284582L), V4 = structure(c(10L, 
10L, 12L, 2L, 10L, 13L), .Label = c(" 10th", " 11th", " 12th", 
" 1st-4th", " 5th-6th", " 7th-8th", " 9th", " Assoc-acdm", " Assoc-voc", 
" Bachelors", " Doctorate", " HS-grad", " Masters", " Preschool", 
" Prof-school", " Some-college"), class = "factor"), V5 = c(13L, 
13L, 9L, 7L, 13L, 14L), V6 = structure(c(5L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
3L), .Label = c(" Divorced", " Married-AF-spouse", " Married-civ-spouse", 
" Married-spouse-absent", " Never-married", " Separated", " Widowed"
), class = "factor"), V7 = structure(c(2L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 11L, 5L
), .Label = c(" ?", " Adm-clerical", " Armed-Forces", " Craft-repair", 
" Exec-managerial", " Farming-fishing", " Handlers-cleaners", 
" Machine-op-inspct", " Other-service", " Priv-house-serv", " Prof-specialty", 
" Protective-serv", " Sales", " Tech-support", " Transport-moving"
), class = "factor"), V8 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 6L
), .Label = c(" Husband", " Not-in-family", " Other-relative", 
" Own-child", " Unmarried", " Wife"), class = "factor"), V9 = structure(c(5L, 
5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L), .Label = c(" Amer-Indian-Eskimo", " Asian-Pac-Islander", 
" Black", " Other", " White"), class = "factor"), V10 = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c(" Female", " Male"), class = "factor"), 
    V11 = c(2174L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), V12 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L), V13 = c(40L, 13L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L), V14 = structure(c(40L, 
    40L, 40L, 40L, 6L, 40L), .Label = c(" ?", " Cambodia", " Canada", 
    " China", " Columbia", " Cuba", " Dominican-Republic", " Ecuador", 
    " El-Salvador", " England", " France", " Germany", " Greece", 
    " Guatemala", " Haiti", " Holand-Netherlands", " Honduras", 
    " Hong", " Hungary", " India", " Iran", " Ireland", " Italy", 
    " Jamaica", " Japan", " Laos", " Mexico", " Nicaragua", " Outlying-US(Guam-USVI-etc)", 
    " Peru", " Philippines", " Poland", " Portugal", " Puerto-Rico", 
    " Scotland", " South", " Taiwan", " Thailand", " Trinadad&Tobago", 
    " United-States", " Vietnam", " Yugoslavia"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6", "V7", "V8", "V9", "V10", "V11", 
"V12", "V13", "V14"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

trainY

```
structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c(" <=50K", " >50K"
), class = "factor")
```

After reading in trainX, trainY, the easiest way to reproduce this problem would be

```
library(C50)
test = C5.0(x=trainX, y=trainY)
```

My actual train Y :

```
structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c(" <=50K", " >50K"), class = "factor")
```

My actual trainX

```
structure(list(age = c(39L, 50L, 38L, 53L, 28L, 37L, 49L, 52L, 
31L, 42L, 37L, 30L, 23L, 32L, 40L, 34L, 25L, 32L, 38L, 43L, 40L, 
54L, 35L, 43L, 59L, 56L, 19L, 54L, 39L, 49L, 23L, 20L, 45L, 30L, 
22L, 48L, 21L, 19L, 31L, 48L, 31L, 53L, 24L, 49L, 25L, 57L, 53L, 
44L, 41L, 29L, 25L, 18L, 47L, 50L, 47L, 43L, 46L, 35L, 41L, 30L, 
30L, 32L, 48L, 42L, 29L, 36L, 28L, 53L, 49L, 25L, 19L, 31L, 29L, 
23L, 79L, 27L, 40L, 67L, 18L, 31L, 18L, 52L, 46L, 59L, 44L, 53L, 
49L, 33L, 30L, 43L, 57L, 37L, 28L, 30L, 34L, 29L, 48L, 37L, 48L, 
32L), workClass = structure(c(8L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 8L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 
5L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 8L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 
5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 8L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 
7L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 
5L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 2L), .Label = c(" ?", 
" Federal-gov", " Local-gov", " Never-worked", " Private", " Self-emp-inc", 
" Self-emp-not-inc", " State-gov", " Without-pay"), class = "factor"), 
    fnlwgt = c(77516L, 83311L, 215646L, 234721L, 338409L, 284582L, 
    160187L, 209642L, 45781L, 159449L, 280464L, 141297L, 122272L, 
    205019L, 121772L, 245487L, 176756L, 186824L, 28887L, 292175L, 
    193524L, 302146L, 76845L, 117037L, 109015L, 216851L, 168294L, 
    180211L, 367260L, 193366L, 190709L, 266015L, 386940L, 59951L, 
    311512L, 242406L, 197200L, 544091L, 84154L, 265477L, 507875L, 
    88506L, 172987L, 94638L, 289980L, 337895L, 144361L, 128354L, 
    101603L, 271466L, 32275L, 226956L, 51835L, 251585L, 109832L, 
    237993L, 216666L, 56352L, 147372L, 188146L, 59496L, 293936L, 
    149640L, 116632L, 105598L, 155537L, 183175L, 169846L, 191681L, 
    200681L, 101509L, 309974L, 162298L, 211678L, 124744L, 213921L, 
    32214L, 212759L, 309634L, 125927L, 446839L, 276515L, 51618L, 
    159937L, 343591L, 346253L, 268234L, 202051L, 54334L, 410867L, 
    249977L, 286730L, 212563L, 117747L, 226296L, 115585L, 191277L, 
    202683L, 171095L, 249409L), education = structure(c(10L, 
    10L, 12L, 2L, 10L, 13L, 7L, 12L, 13L, 10L, 16L, 10L, 10L, 
    8L, 9L, 6L, 12L, 12L, 2L, 13L, 11L, 12L, 7L, 2L, 12L, 10L, 
    12L, 16L, 12L, 12L, 8L, 16L, 10L, 16L, 16L, 2L, 16L, 12L, 
    16L, 8L, 7L, 10L, 10L, 12L, 12L, 10L, 12L, 13L, 9L, 9L, 16L, 
    12L, 15L, 10L, 12L, 16L, 5L, 9L, 12L, 12L, 10L, 6L, 12L, 
    11L, 16L, 12L, 16L, 12L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 10L, 10L, 16L, 16L, 
    12L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 12L, 10L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 
    7L, 11L, 9L, 16L, 16L, 12L, 10L, 16L, 11L, 16L, 8L, 12L), .Label = c(" 10th", 
    " 11th", " 12th", " 1st-4th", " 5th-6th", " 7th-8th", " 9th", 
    " Assoc-acdm", " Assoc-voc", " Bachelors", " Doctorate", 
    " HS-grad", " Masters", " Preschool", " Prof-school", " Some-college"
    ), class = "factor"), educationNum = c(13L, 13L, 9L, 7L, 
    13L, 14L, 5L, 9L, 14L, 13L, 10L, 13L, 13L, 12L, 11L, 4L, 
    9L, 9L, 7L, 14L, 16L, 9L, 5L, 7L, 9L, 13L, 9L, 10L, 9L, 9L, 
    12L, 10L, 13L, 10L, 10L, 7L, 10L, 9L, 10L, 12L, 5L, 13L, 
    13L, 9L, 9L, 13L, 9L, 14L, 11L, 11L, 10L, 9L, 15L, 13L, 9L, 
    10L, 3L, 11L, 9L, 9L, 13L, 4L, 9L, 16L, 10L, 9L, 10L, 9L, 
    10L, 10L, 10L, 13L, 13L, 10L, 10L, 9L, 12L, 6L, 7L, 4L, 9L, 
    13L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 14L, 5L, 16L, 11L, 10L, 10L, 9L, 
    13L, 10L, 16L, 10L, 12L, 9L), marital = structure(c(5L, 3L, 
    1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 
    5L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 
    1L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 
    1L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
    3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 
    3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 
    1L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 5L), .Label = c(" Divorced", 
    " Married-AF-spouse", " Married-civ-spouse", " Married-spouse-absent", 
    " Never-married", " Separated", " Widowed"), class = "factor"), 
    occ = structure(c(2L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 11L, 5L, 9L, 5L, 11L, 5L, 
    5L, 11L, 2L, 13L, 4L, 15L, 6L, 8L, 13L, 5L, 11L, 9L, 6L, 
    15L, 14L, 14L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 12L, 13L, 5L, 2L, 9L, 8L, 
    8L, 2L, 13L, 11L, 8L, 11L, 14L, 2L, 7L, 11L, 8L, 5L, 4L, 
    11L, 5L, 9L, 11L, 5L, 5L, 14L, 8L, 9L, 2L, 8L, 13L, 1L, 15L, 
    11L, 14L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 11L, 13L, 13L, 8L, 11L, 9L, 
    2L, 1L, 9L, 6L, 13L, 9L, 9L, 13L, 4L, 13L, 12L, 11L, 13L, 
    11L, 11L, 4L, 8L, 13L, 12L, 7L, 11L, 13L, 5L, 9L), .Label = c(" ?", 
    " Adm-clerical", " Armed-Forces", " Craft-repair", " Exec-managerial", 
    " Farming-fishing", " Handlers-cleaners", " Machine-op-inspct", 
    " Other-service", " Priv-house-serv", " Prof-specialty", 
    " Protective-serv", " Sales", " Tech-support", " Transport-moving"
    ), class = "factor"), relationship = structure(c(2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 
    5L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    5L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
    1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 
    5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 4L), .Label = c(" Husband", " Not-in-family", 
    " Other-relative", " Own-child", " Unmarried", " Wife"), class = "factor"), 
    race = structure(c(5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    3L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L
    ), .Label = c(" Amer-Indian-Eskimo", " Asian-Pac-Islander", 
    " Black", " Other", " White"), class = "factor"), sex = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c(" Female", 
    " Male"), class = "factor"), capGain = c(2174L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 14084L, 5178L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 5013L, 2407L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 14344L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), capLoss = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2042L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1408L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1902L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1573L, 0L, 0L, 1902L, 0L, 0L, 0L), hours = c(40L, 
    13L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 16L, 45L, 50L, 40L, 80L, 40L, 30L, 
    50L, 40L, 45L, 35L, 40L, 50L, 45L, 60L, 20L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 
    40L, 40L, 60L, 80L, 40L, 52L, 44L, 40L, 40L, 15L, 40L, 40L, 
    25L, 38L, 40L, 43L, 40L, 50L, 40L, 35L, 40L, 38L, 40L, 40L, 
    43L, 40L, 30L, 60L, 55L, 60L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 48L, 40L, 40L, 
    40L, 40L, 45L, 58L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 50L, 40L, 32L, 40L, 70L, 
    40L, 20L, 40L, 40L, 2L, 22L, 40L, 30L, 40L, 40L, 48L, 40L, 
    35L, 40L, 50L, 40L, 50L, 40L, 40L, 25L, 35L, 40L, 50L, 60L, 
    48L, 40L, 40L), country = structure(c(40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 
    6L, 40L, 24L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 20L, 40L, 40L, 1L, 27L, 
    40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 36L, 
    40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 34L, 40L, 40L, 1L, 40L, 
    40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 1L, 
    17L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 27L, 34L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 1L, 40L, 40L, 
    40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 27L, 
    40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 6L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 
    40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 1L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 10L, 40L
    ), .Label = c(" ?", " Cambodia", " Canada", " China", " Columbia", 
    " Cuba", " Dominican-Republic", " Ecuador", " El-Salvador", 
    " England", " France", " Germany", " Greece", " Guatemala", 
    " Haiti", " Holand-Netherlands", " Honduras", " Hong", " Hungary", 
    " India", " Iran", " Ireland", " Italy", " Jamaica", " Japan", 
    " Laos", " Mexico", " Nicaragua", " Outlying-US(Guam-USVI-etc)", 
    " Peru", " Philippines", " Poland", " Portugal", " Puerto-Rico", 
    " Scotland", " South", " Taiwan", " Thailand", " Trinadad&Tobago", 
    " United-States", " Vietnam", " Yugoslavia"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("age", 
"workClass", "fnlwgt", "education", "educationNum", "marital", 
"occ", "relationship", "race", "sex", "capGain", "capLoss", "hours", 
"country"), row.names = c(NA, 100L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you please make sure your example is [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Include your data in a form that's more agreeable for copt/pasting. If we can run the code it will be easier for is to help you.

Comment: Is there a place I can upload the data? What would be best way for formatting it on here for that? @MrFlick

Comment: Read the link i provided for sharing a minimal, reproducible example.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice it was a link.  I've included dput's now for my training variables. 5 examples of each was enough to show that decision tree is using my Y-variable in the decision making process.

Comment: If your Y have one dominant label, the decision tree that you trained may identify everything as dominant label. So you can down sample dominant label randomly to fix this. Or use loss matrix while training. I did not use this package but there must be loss matrix argument in the function.

Answer (score 1):

The code you provided constructs a factor with 1 level (`<=50k`) because the first vector input contains only `1L`s. You should assign these labels accordingly or use an easier way to construct your response variable - something like `trainY <- as.factor(...)`.
I changed the way `trainY` is constructed to:

```
y <- structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c(" <=50K", " >50K"), class = "factor")
```

and after re-training the tree with same commands i got:

```
Decision tree:

V14 = Cuba: >50K (1)
V14 in {?,Cambodia,Canada,China,Columbia,Dominican-Republic,Ecuador,
    El-Salvador,England,France,Germany,Greece,Guatemala,Haiti,
    Holand-Netherlands,Honduras,Hong,Hungary,India,Iran,Ireland,Italy,
    Jamaica,Japan,Laos,Mexico,Nicaragua,Outlying-US(Guam-USVI-etc),Peru,
    Philippines,Poland,Portugal,Puerto-Rico,Scotland,South,Taiwan,Thailand,
    Trinadad&Tobago,United-States,Vietnam,Yugoslavia}: <=50K (5/1)
```

Make sure you don't have only one class in the response when passing args to `C5.0`. hth

**UPDATE**
After plotting some of the predictors vs response I noticed that `education` and `educationNum` show the clearest division in the data (`Doctorate` implies `>50K` immediately). Next step was to tweak some of the very useful `C5.0 Control` options - they are well documented in the `C5.0` [package documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/C50/C50.pdf) and the official informal [tutorial page](https://www.rulequest.com/see5-unix.html) - check them out they give you broad control over the classification controls.
For example:

```
C5.0(x = trainX,y = trainY,control = C5.0Control(subset = T, winnow = T,minCases = 4,fuzzyThreshold = T))

Decision tree:

educationNum <= 13 (14.5): <=50K (95/20)
educationNum >= 16 (14.5): >50K (5)
```

similiarly, doing some "feature engineering" which in this case meant just leaving out some of the columns from the original dataframe produced :

```
C5.0(x = trainX[ ,c(1:5, 9:13)], y = trainY)

Decision tree:

educationNum <= 14: <=50K (95/20)
educationNum > 14: >50K (5)
```

I believe that there is no one general "out of the box" `C5.0` defaults setting that would produce satisfying results for all kinds of problems, so it really comes down to trying out different parameter settings, features etc...but as with all things `R` there is plenty of material around to give you some direction.

Comment: Hello sir!

Thanks for the help!  The problem I'm having though is slightly more complex. I didn't realize in my example that I was going to have the issue of them all being <=50K.

In the code I was running, I was using 100 examples (didnt want to paste them all here) and had a mix of <=50K and >50K.  The issue goes away if I use a larger sample size (150), but I don't think that should matter.  This answer of yours was helpful, but if you can, I have posted the larger Y-set I am using above. If you see any issues please let me know? @davidski

Comment: To clarify - Was using 100 examples with a mix of 1L and 2L, still got a 1-level classifier. Doesn't make sense. Goes away when using 150 examples.  Want to use 100 though.  Why is this an issue? New dput() editted in OP. Thanks!